# Gradle task executing

Tags: groovy, gradle

The following gradle build script

```
task hello << {
            println "task hello"
}

hello << {
   println "th"
}
```

produces output:

```
task hello
th
```

But one's order reversing caused error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 
> Could not find property 'hello' on root project
```

What is that error about? Could you explain it with the Groovy's point of view?

Comment: Of course, if you literally just swap those code segments around, there will be no "`task`" in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be translated in Java pseudo-code the following way:

```
Task task = project.addTask("hello");
task.doLast(() -> println("hello"));

task = project.getTaskByName("hello"); // works fine, because a task "hello" has bee added before
task.doLast(() -> println("th"));
```

If you switch the two operations, you get

```
Task task = project.getTaskByName("hello"); // doesn't work, because no task "hello" has been defined before
task.doLast(() -> println("th"));

task = project.addTask("hello");
task.doLast(() -> println("hello"));
```

And obviously, since you're trying to modify a task that hasn't been defined yet, that doesn't work.